# Using the class Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application, how can I get the list of authentications?

Tags: c#, iis-7

I'm trying to write some C# code to do administration on IIS.

I have an instance of Microsoft.Web.Administration.Application for my web application.

How can I use this object to get the same information as in IIS under "Authentication"?

I expect a list that contains something like:

- Anonymous Authentication (disabled)
- ASP.NET Impersonation (enabled)
- Forms Authentication (disabled)
- Windows Authentication (enabled)

Thanks in advance,
Stephen

Comment: What have you tried?  By asking for only code you make this question localized to your problem and less helpful to future users.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand, Ramhound.  What should I ask for instead of code?  Properties?  Methods?  Classes?

Comment: @LostHobbit The idea here is that you try something by yourself first and only if you fail, you kindly ask how to solve. This also means that you should write what you have tried so far.

Comment: [Here is an explanation on **how to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Fair enough.  I've looked at the properties of the class and cannot find anything that looks like I can use it to access authentication information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Configuration configuration = Application.GetWebConfiguration();
```

Then use

```
configuration.GetMetadata("availableSections")
```

...to get a list of sections.  The authentication sections start with "system.webServer/security/authentication/", so search for those sections.

Then call

```
Application.GetWebConfiguration().GetSection([SECTION]).GetAttributeValue("enabled")
```

The section for Anonymous Authentication is called "anonymousAuthentication", and the section for Windows Authentication is "windowsAuthentication".

There's also Forms Authentication, which is explained further down.  So the code looks something like this:

```
const string authenticationPrefix = "system.webServer/security/authentication/";

private Dictionary<string, string> authenticationDescriptions = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{ 
    {"anonymousAuthentication", "Anonymous Authentication"},
    {"windowsAuthentication", "Windows Authentication"},
};

Configuration configuration = application.GetWebConfiguration();

IEnumerable<string> authentications = ((String)configuration.GetMetadata("availableSections")).Split(',').Where(
    authentication => authentication.StartsWith(authenticationPrefix));

foreach (string authentication in authentications)
{
    string authName = authentication.Substring(authenticationPrefix.Length);
    string authDesc;
    authenticationDescriptions.TryGetValue(authName, out authDesc);
    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(authDesc))
        continue;
    authenticationCheckedListBox.Items.Add(authDesc, (bool)configuration.GetSection(authentication).GetAttributeValue("enabled"));
}
```

Here's the code for Forms Authentication

```
enum FormsAuthentication { Off = 1, On = 3 };

ConfigurationSection authenticationSection = configuration.GetSection("system.web/authentication");

authenticationCheckedListBox.Items.Add("Forms Authentication", (FormsAuthentication)authenticationSection.GetAttributeValue("mode") == FormsAuthentication.On);
```